# Problem with VSC , live server and media queries

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, media-queries

[simple video of my problem](https://streamable.com/45i2mw)

My media queries wont work at all so I create the most simple test to show up my issue.
but its work here with the snippet ... but not locally with VSC ...
Why ? and how can I resolve it ?

```css
body{
    background-color: aqua;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also put this test on my test server and wont work at all 
http://test.shader.blue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to work correctly when I check it in Device Tool Bar of Chrome. Try it in dev tools(f12).
Chrome documentation : https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/

Latest browsers don't go less than 500px in width when you try to make the window smaller. That is the reason why you dont see blue in your video. If you still want to try using the browser width, try changing 480px to 600px. You will be able to see the Media Queries working then.